# how to print the ASCII code of an entered character

Tags: c

I have these codes

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d",(int)a);

}
```

My question is,when i type a as an input,i get 45 as ASCII equivalent and now i decided to  change these codes to:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int a;
    scanf("%c",&a);
    printf("%d",(int)a);

}
```

It shows the righteous answer which is 97 and i do not understand what difference %c made.

Comment: i'm not sure which compiler you're using, but i'm not getting 45 as output from your first program and typing 'a' doesn't put anything in variable a.

Comment: @rakib `45` is the garbage value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enter a `char` to `int a; scanf("%d",&a);`, it skips taking the input. The `char` stays in the input buffer and the previous value of `a` is retained. So in your case, `45` is the initial garbage value of `a`.

However, when you input as a character as in `int a; scanf("%c",&a);`, the character is taken from the input buffer, and its integer equivalent is stored in `a`.